# Java: Changing a Binary number like 1010 and reversing the bits. 1010 = 0101. 0's to 1's and 1's to 0's

Tags: java, binary, integer

I have been searching around the web and seems like I can never seem to find the answer to this question. How do you change the bits in a binary number?

> Example: say I got 1010 and I want to change the numbers 0's to 1's and 1's to 0's.

Right now, I have the binary number in a integer.

I'm completely stumped, if anyone could help me thank you.

Sorry if people are confused from my question . What i want to do is change the numbers 0's to 1's and 1's to 0's .

Comment: `0b1010 ^ 0xFF`.

Comment: Are you trying to reverse the bits or negate them? Your example is not clear, what do you expect for 01100 for example? 10011 or 00110

Comment: @ErkanHaspulat: excellent point. It is unclear if he wants to xor/toggle or reverse the order.

Comment: I would use 0b1010 ^ 0xFF but i can't. Im current using eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to flip all the bits you can do

```
int i = 0b1010;
```

or in Java 6

```
int i = Integer.parseInt("1010", 2);
int i2 = ~i; // toggle 0 and 1's.
int i3 = i ^ 0xFF; // toggle the lower 8 bit only.
```

or you can try

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    System.out.println(toggleBits("1010"));
    System.out.println(toggleBits("00001010"));
    System.out.println(toggleBits("1100001010"));
}

private static String toggleBits(String s) {
    long i = Long.parseLong(s, 2);
    long i2 = i ^ ((1L << s.length()) - 1);
    String s2 = Long.toBinaryString(i2);
    while (s2.length() < s.length()) s2 = '0' + s2;
    return s2;
}
```

Comment: Note that the 0b syntax only works as of Java 7 (not an issue for me but may be for some.)

Comment: hmm what im currently using is Eclipse, how would i change it so it would work for me?

Comment: I don't know how to change eclipse to use Java 7, but I bet google knows. ;)

Comment: Could you be more specific? What don't you get?

Comment: Thank you! I will try using this now.

Answer (score 1):

Are you not just looking for this method on Integer: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#reverse(int)?

This should do the trick.

Comment: Not after he clarified the question, though... +1 anyway because I did not know that method.

Comment: Trying to use that standard API (discovering some new things myself ;)) it seems like a standard method on BigInteger: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#xor(java.math.BigInteger). No idea if this is appropriate for your usecase.

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to do bit reversing operation similar to **string reverse** operation, then I think Java has a method named "`reverse()`" (or similar) which will work for you, I guess. You can also try the answer by **@Dozz**.

Answer (score 0):

A quick demonstration for what was discussed and suggested in the comments would be:

```
    int i = 42;
    int j = i ^ 0xFF;
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(i));
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(j));
```

See more about XOR [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or).